# How can I display information from a JSON file in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, web-deployment

This is my code for the Transactions page here am linking all data and setting the data that I want to display.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import axios from "axios";
import F_data from "./FakeTransactions.json";

function DataGridForTransactions() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(F_data).then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    { field: "transaction_id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
    { field: "amount", headerName: "Amount", width: 150 },
    { field: "transaction_type", headerName: "Type", width: 150 },
    { field: "description", headerName: "Description", width: 150 },
    { field: "transaction_date", headerName: "Date", width: 150 },
  ];

  const rows = data.map((row) => {
    return {
      transaction_id: row.transaction_id,
      amount: row.amount,
      transaction_type: row.transaction_type,
      description: row.description,
      transaction_date: row.transaction_date,
    };
  });

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500, width: "flex" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOption={[5]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default DataGridForTransactions;
```

It shows the data grid but not the rows with the information.

This is the Json file:

```
"data": [
    {
      "transaction_id": "1",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-01",
      "transaction_type": "debit",
      "amount": -100.5,
      "description": "ATM withdrawal"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "2",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-02",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 50,
      "description": "Paycheck deposit"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "3",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-03",
      "transaction_type": "debit",
      "amount": -75,
      "description": "Online purchase"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "4",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-04",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 250,
      "description": "Gift from family"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "5",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-05",
      "transaction_type": "debit",
      "amount": -125,
      "description": "Grocery shopping"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "6",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-06",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 300,
      "description": "Investment return"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "7",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-07",
      "transaction_type": "debit",
      "amount": -50,
      "description": "Gasoline purchase"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "8",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-08",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 100,
      "description": "Groceries"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "9",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-09",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 100,
      "description": "Eating Out"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "10",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-10",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 100,
      "description": "Gasoline purchase"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "11",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-11",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 10,
      "description": "Candy"
    },
    {
      "transaction_id": "12",
      "account_number": "1234567890123456",
      "transaction_date": "2022-01-12",
      "transaction_type": "credit",
      "amount": 1000,
      "description": "Paycheck deposit"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I am linking everything and using Axios to get the info from the JSON file but I get an error as if it doesn't get any information.

Comment: "I get an error" could be... a bit more specific.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton the error i am getting it says uncaught (promise)

Comment: It seems as it can't find the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

To display data from a JSON file in a Material-UI data grid, you can use the "useState" and "useEffect" hooks in React to fetch the data from the JSON file and store it in a state variable. You can then pass this state variable as a prop to the Material-UI data grid component. Here is an example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import MUIDataTable from 'mui-datatables';

function MyComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('path/to/json/file')
            .then(response => setData(response.data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }, []);

    const columns = ["Name", "Age", "Address"];

    return (
        <MUIDataTable
            title={"Employee List"}
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
        />
    );
}
```

In the above example the `useEffect` hook is used to fetch the data from the JSON file when the component is first rendered.

The "axios" library is used to make the GET request to the JSON file, and the response data is stored in the "data" state variable.

Finally, the "MUIDataTable" component is rendered, and the "data" state variable is passed as a prop to the component so that it can be displayed in the data grid.

Comment: This is exactly what I got above... there is nothing different from what I got